# MySqlConnection ADO.Net High CPU Usage

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, windows-services

I have multi-threading application where N threads are accessing the MySQL Database. Each query will create its own **MySqlConnection** intance to avoid sharing of **MySqlDataReader**. 
However we are encountering CPU spikes to our database server. 
I already tried running **SHOW PROCESSLIST** but there are no slow queries in the results. I suspect the root cause is how the threads handle the connections.

The following is my query method example.

```
public List<Configuration> GetAlertConfigByDeviceID(string deviceID) 
{
    List<Configuration> configurations =  new List<Configuration>();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(WinAlerterConfig.WebConnectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbCommand.CommandText = StoredProcedures.SqlGetAlertCfgDetailByDeviceID;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("DeviceID", deviceID));

                using (MySqlDataReader dbResultSet = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dbResultSet.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dbResultSet.Read())
                        {
                            configurations.Add(new Configuration()
                            {
                                ConfigID = dbResultSet.GetUInt64Safe(0),
                                AlertType = dbResultSet.GetUInt64Safe(1),
                                ZoneID = dbResultSet.GetUInt64Safe(2),
                                Timeout = dbResultSet.GetInt64Safe(3),
                                DeviceID = dbResultSet.GetStringSafe(4),
                                FromZoneID = dbResultSet.GetUInt64Safe(5),
                                OtherZoneAlert = dbResultSet.GetBooleanSafe(6),
                                Remarks = dbResultSet.GetStringSafe(7)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    dbResultSet.Close();
                    dbResultSet.Dispose();
                }
                dbCommand.Dispose();
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
            dbConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogErrorLine("GetAlertConfigByDeviceID: {0} {1} {2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogErrorLine("GetAlertConfigByDeviceID: {0} {1} {2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace);
    }

    return configurations;
}
```

---

I also included **"polling = true;"** in our connection string. So I assume that MySQL or ADO.net will handle the Connection pool.

Did I do something wrong in my method? Is connection pooling already handled by ADO.net already?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your Close and Dispose calls. The using block are already taking care of disposal.

Also make sure you have an index on the deviceId column.

Then try again.

Comment: What should 'thread_handling' value be in SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  ?  Thanks

Comment: What should 'thread_handling' value be in SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for this type ADO connection?  Thanks